# MySql CASE expression with two input columns

Tags: mysql, case, mysql-error-1241

I'm looking to use a case expression in mysql with two columns as input. This is how I would like to format the code. All code snippets use `Set @a = 0; Set @b = 0;` at the start, although those values can be modified. My own use case has several values each could be (more than 2 each).

```
SELECT 
    CASE (@a , @b)
        WHEN (0 , 0) THEN 'Both zero'
        WHEN (1 , 0) THEN 'a is 1'
        WHEN (0 , 1) THEN 'b is 1'
        WHEN (1 , 1) THEN 'both 1'
        ELSE NULL
    END;
```

When using the case statement this way, MySql throws `Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)`.
For reference, both of the following work, which makes me curious why the above doesn't.

```
SELECT 
    IF((@a , @b) = (0 , 0),
        'Both zero',
        IF((@a , @b) = (1 , 0),
            'a is 1',
            IF((@a , @b) = (0 , 1),
                'b is 1',
                IF((@a , @b) = (1 , 1), 'both 1', NULL))));
```

and

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN (@a , @b) = (0 , 0) THEN 'Both zero'
        WHEN (@a , @b) = (1 , 0) THEN 'a is 1'
        WHEN (@a , @b) = (0 , 1) THEN 'b is 1'
        WHEN (@a , @b) = (1 , 1) THEN 'both 1'
        ELSE NULL
    END;
```

So, the question:
Can I use a CASE expression like the first code snippet when doing a multi-column comparison?
If so, please provide an example. If not, why not?

The 3rd method is completely viable for my own use case, but if @a and @b were select statements, it wouldn't be.
The ideal would be a solution that:

1. Only runs inputs once, if they were select statements.
2. Can be easily expanded upon for any number of inputs.
3. Is agnostic to the input types (IE (@a,@b) = (0,'!@#$:abc') is a valid case to check).

Comment: Not possible. You cannot have "lists of values" in a `case` statement. `case` takes one SINGLE value, and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the short version of `CASE` with multiple values. You need to use the long version that tests both conditions with `AND`

```
CASE 
    WHEN @a = 0 AND @b = 0 THEN 'Both zero'
    WHEN @a = 1 AND @b = 0 THEN 'a is 1'
    WHEN @a = 0 AND @b = 1 THEN 'b is 1'
    WHEN @a = 1 AND @b = 1 THEN 'Both 1'
    ELSE NULL
END
```

Another option is to concatenate them.

```
CASE CONCAT(@a, @b)
    WHEN '00' THEN 'Both zero'
    WHEN '10' THEN 'a is 1'
    WHEN '01' THEN 'b is 1'
    WHWN '11' THEN 'Both 1'
    ELSE NULL
END
```